# "Unknown option `poster' for package `tcolorbox'" yet the library is loaded

Tags: tcolorbox, posters

I am trying to use the `poster` library for the tcolorbox package, and, following the [tcolorbox manual](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), I am loading this library via

```
   \usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
```

in the preamble.
When I compile (`pdflatex`) I always get the following error:

```
   ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `poster' for package `tcolorbox'.
```

I also tried to put the following line in my preamble

```
   \tcbuselibrary{poster}
```

which should be equivalent to the option in the above `\usepackage` statement (according to the tcolorbox manual). I get the following message:

```
   ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/library/poster' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

No matter what combination of the two methods I try, I still get this type of error.

Finally I noticed there was no `tcbposter.code.tex` file in my `texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/` directory, and I thought this was the source of the error. So I downloaded it from [this link](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) and put it in this directory, but I still get the same error.

Here is a MWE (or rather MnotWE):

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}

   \usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
   \usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
   \pagestyle{empty}

   \begin{document}
     \begin{tcbposter}[
     coverage = {spread},
     poster = {showframe,columns=4,rows=5},
     ]
     \end{poster}
   \end{document}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: The poster library of `tcolorbox` seems to pretty new. Do you really have the newest version of `tcolorbox` installed? There's also a typo: `\end{poster}` should mean `\end{tcbposter}`, most likely

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I have already tried (on Ubuntu) `sudo apt-get texlive` to see if I was up to date (since it seems to be included in TeXLive), and I am. Is this the right way to ensure I have the latest version? And it is not a typo, I actually copied this example (after having tried it with no success) from http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox-tutorial-poster.pdf.

Comment: The Ubuntu `texlive` packages are rather outdated (as are for debian or OpenSuSE). I don't recommend them. Rather use a clear vanilla install over the net.

Comment: Thank you. I know I could find how to do this, but if you could give me the main steps for this clear install I would greatly appreciate :)

Comment: I think, you should read http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html and download http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz. You should also use `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}` in order to see which version of `tcolorbox` is loaded -- if it is not `4.10`, you're loading an older version of `tcolorbox` instead of the version from CTAN, which I don't recommend in this case. The package manager of the TeX distribution is to be preferred

Comment: Thank you very much. With `\listfiles` in the preamble, I effectively have `tcolorbox 2016/02/29 version 3.90` in my `.log` file.

Comment: Yes, that's too old by far (more than one year lagging behind the current version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `poster` library is a new feature of `tcolorbox` from version 4.10, dating back to 2017/07/05, the previous release `4.03` does not provide `poster`.

The `Changes` file from 4.10 clearly states at the end:

> version 4.10 (2017/07/05)
>
> - new options:   'inherit height', 'verbatim ignore percent'
> - library 'skins'   * new style 'enhanced standard jigsaw'
> - library 'magazine':   * new macro: '\ifboxarrayempty'
> - library 'breakable':   * option 'break at' allows negative values now.
> - the algorithm for breaks inside a multicolumn environment was
>     improved
>
>   (user code may be affected by this change).   * new macro: '\tcbbreak'
> - library 'minted':   * the default settings for 'minted options'
>     are supplemented by 'breaklines,autogobble'
> - new library 'poster'   * new macros and environments:
>     'tcbposter',  '\tcbposterset', '\posterbox', 'posterboxenv',
>     'tcbposterwidth', 'tcbposterheight', 'tcbpostercolspacing', 'tcbposterrowspacing',
>     'tcbpostercolumns', 'tcbposterrows', 'tcbpostercolwidth', 'tcbposterrowheight'   * new options:
>     'poster', 'columns', 'rows', 'colspacing', 'rowspacing', 'spacing',
>     'showframe', 'width', 'height', 'prefix', 'coverage', 'no coverage',
>     'boxes', 'fontsize', 'name', 'column', 'column*', 'span', 'row', 'rowspan',
>     'fixed height', 'below', 'above', 'at', 'between', 'sequence',
>     'placeholder', 'xshift', 'yshift'
> - New example file 'tcolorbox-example-poster'
> - New tutorial 'tcolorbox-tutorial-poster' for poster creation

The corrected code

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
 \usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
 \pagestyle{empty}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tcbposter}[
   coverage = {spread},
   poster = {showframe,columns=4,rows=5},
   ]
 \end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

gives this output:

[image]